# How to make vue-loader process the same block multiple times, using different loaders

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-loader

**UPDATE**

Additional details can be found in the [Nuxt feature request](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3796) that I created.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I'm using [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) to build a pattern library app. My goal is to display the uncompiled SASS beside each rendered component, like this:

**Public-facing .html page:**

```html
<div class="my-component"></div>

<pre>
  <code>
    @import "assets/stylesheets/colors";

    .my-component {
      color: $some-color;
    }
  </code>
</pre>
```

Following [this example](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/custom-blocks.html#example), I was able to create a custom `<docs>` language block:

**.vue file:**

```html
<docs>
  @import "assets/stylesheets/colors";
  ...
</docs>

<style lang="scss">
  @import "assets/stylesheets/colors";
  ...
</style>
```

This works, but it forces me to duplicate my code. It would be much better if I could eliminate the `<docs>` block and process the `<style>` block twice, using two different loaders. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to do this.

I tried the following, hoping that `vue-loader` would process both the `<docs>` block and the `<style>` block, but only the `<docs>` block is being processed (probably because the `<style>` block is nested?), so my SCSS is no longer being compiled and injected into the page:

**.vue file:**

```html
<docs>
  <style lang="scss">
    @import "assets/stylesheets/colors";
    ...
  </style>
</docs>
```

I'm using [Nuxt Edge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-edge), which includes Webpack 4 and Vue Loader 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading though the [Vue Loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) code and hacking around, I don't think it's possible to run a single block through multiple sets of loaders (please correct me if I'm wrong). Nevertheless, I was able to find an adequate solution to my problem:

I ended up using [Copy Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) to duplicate my `.vue` files and save them with a `.txt` extension. I then request them via Axios (on the client side), or use FS to read them from the file system (on the server side). I then extract the `<style>` and `<script>` blocks via regex. This isn't ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try seperate css into seperate files like this:

```
<docs src="/the/path/component.scss"></docs>
<style src="/the/path/component.scss"></styles>
```

then write a loader to read the file's content and render it.

Comment: Thanks Zmen. Someone suggested this in the Nuxt [Discord](https://discordapp.com/) chatroom too, and it seems like my best option. I've been hacking around in the Nuxt internals trying to make this work without moving the SCSS into a separate file, but I've been unsuccessful. I'm going to wait a few more days to see if any other solutions crop up before accepting your answer.

Comment: My custom loader executes when I add my new `/\.scss$/` rule to `nuxt.config.js`, but it throws an error because `vue-loader` expects it to return CSS instead of JavaScript.

Comment: I tried Zmen's suggestion. This works: `<style src="./style.scss" lang="scss"></style>`. And this works: `<docs src="./style.txt"></docs>`. But when I try to pass the `<docs>` block a SASS file instead of a text file, it gives me a JavaScript function instead of the contents of the file: `// style-loader: Adds some css to the DOM by adding a <style> tag // load the styles var content = require("!!../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js??...`. It seems like it's still trying to use Style Loader even though I'm running it through a custom loader.

Comment: My loader looks like this (apologies for the single-line formatting): `module.exports = function(source, map) { this.callback(null, 'export default function (Component) { Component.options.__foobar = ' + JSON.stringify(source) + '}', map) }`